# Uml Class diagram [verification]

Tags: uml

A family composed of Father, Mother and Children are working towards devising a schedule for keeping track of the chores around the house. Usually, the father mows the lawn, but sometimes he is able to delegate this chore to his children. When none of the children are available, the father will hire a professional lawn mower. The professional lawn mower will need to capture the information about this family on his schedule, that will comprise information about: family name, address, telephone number, day/time to mow, duration of mowing. The family lawn will need to be taken care of by seeding and fertilizing treatments. With each mow, the height of the lawn will change. The family would like to keep track of the last time the lawn was seeded, and last time it was fertilized.

I would like to know whether my  Class diagram is correct for the above question.
Below is my link
http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/7426061

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. So the children inherit just from the father? What kind of aliens are that?

Comment: I thought that was pretty funny too.  Children aren't a specialization of parents, though.  Parents have attributes that children don't, the obvious one being children.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a school coursework or something looking from the case-studie. If you do it yourself you will learn or ask tutor for help.